# Suggested fix for Cauchy-Schwartz inequality in Tom Apostol's Calculus (page 42)

Tags: calculus, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Cauchy-Schwarz Theorem I.41 in Tom Apostol's Calculus says that if $a_1, ..., a_n, b_1, ..., b_n $ are arbitrary real numbers, we have:

$$
(\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k b_k)^2 \leq (\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2)(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k^2)
$$

and that the equality sign holds if an only if there is a real number x such that $a_kx + b_k = 0$. The problem with that is that the equality holds even if $a_k = 0$ for each $k$, independently of $b_k$. What would be the suggested fix to the theorem, so that it is correct, but also useful?

Thanks!

Comment: In a more general formulation, equality holds if & only if the vectors $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ are collinear.

Comment: Yes, there are many variants, but it seems that Tom Apostol was very careful not to overload the reader by introducing some concepts (like collinearity) too early, so I was looking for something that would fit the available concepts he already defined by then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equality holds iff there is  a number $x$ such that $a_k x+b_k=0$ for all $k$ OR there is  a number $x$ such that $b_k x+a_k=0$ for all $k$.

The only case when the original proof fails is when $a_k=0$ for each $k$ and this can be resolved by introducing this alternate condition.

Comment: That is probably good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In fact what @TomApostol & @KaviRamaMurthy said, are another form of thinking about just this equation: $a_k x + b_k = 0$, but also accept of $x = \infty$, as a solution too, instead of considering another one: $b_k y + a_k = 0$ with $y = 0$, or equivalency $\forall_k: a_k = 0$, as the superseded solution. Notice that both equations above, have conjugate solutions with relation: $xy = 1$.